# Pandas' groupby doesn't process categoritcal columns in agg function

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, aggregate, categorical-data

I have a Dataframe with 3 columns, two being categorial data and one float16. When I do a groupby and run a lambda specific function in the agg to process each column differently according to the dtype there is a drop on the categorical column.

If done this way, it does work.

```
i=pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","a","a","b","c","c"],"B":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"C":[ "NaN" ,"b","NaN","b","c","c"]})
i['A'] = i['A'].astype('category')   
i['B'] = i['B'].astype('float16')   
i.groupby("A", as_index=False)[["B","C"]].agg(lambda x: x.mean() if np.dtype(x)=='float16' else x.value_counts().index[0])
```

The output, which is what I would like to get to is:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   2.0 NaN
1   b   4.0 b
2   c   5.5 c
```

However whenever I declare column C to be categorical, python automatically drops column C.

```
i=pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","a","a","b","c","c"],"B":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"C":[ "NaN" ,"b","NaN","b","c","c"]})
i['A'] = i['A'].astype('category')   
i['B'] = i['B'].astype('float16')   
i['C'] = i['C'].astype('category')  
i.groupby("A", as_index=False)[["B","C"]].agg(lambda x: x.mean() if np.dtype(x)=='float16' else x.value_counts().index[0])
```

And the answer is as follows:

```
['C'] did not aggregate successfully. If any error is raised this will raise in a future version of pandas. Drop these columns/ops to avoid this warning.

A   B
0   a   2.0
1   b   4.0
2   c   5.5
```

Does anyone known whether agg from groupby is not able to handle categorical columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`category` is a `pandas` data type. `numpy` doesn't necessarily play well with it (`np.dtype(i.C)` gives an error). Use the `pandas.Series.dtype` and it should work as expected.

```
foo = lambda x: x.mean() if x.dtype =='float16' else x.value_counts().index[0]
i.groupby("A", as_index=False)[["B","C"]].agg(foo)
#    A    B    C
# 0  a  2.0  NaN
# 1  b  4.0    b
# 2  c  5.5    c
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice you are not retrieving the type correctly:

```py
i.groupby("A", as_index=False)[["B","C"]].agg(lambda x: print(np.dtype(x)))
```

Gives "None", instead use `x.dtype=='float16'` since `x` is `pd.Series`. You could check with `.agg(lambda x: print(type(x)))`:

```py
i['A'] = i['A'].astype('category')   
i['B'] = i['B'].astype('float16')   
i['C'] = i['C'].astype('category')
i.groupby("A", as_index=False)[["B","C"]].agg(lambda x: x.mean() if x.dtype=='float16' else x.value_counts().index[0])
```

Gives:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   2.0 NaN
1   b   4.0 b
2   c   5.5 c
```